# Quickest way to find the latest installed version of the .NET framework?

Tags: windows, .net-framework

I always forget what version(s) of the .NET framework (and their service packs) I've got installed. Whenever I need to find out, I end up trawling through a long list of updates performed by Windows Update, or, failing that, looking in Add/Remove Programs.

Is there a quicker way?

Comment: It would have been a nice Windows 7 feature along the lines of "How much RAM is on this computer" start menu keyword search to be able to just ask "What version of .net is on this computer".

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: *[How to detect what .NET Framework versions and service packs are installed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199080)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Scott Hanselman created a nice [webpage](http://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/) which tells you which .NET Framework is installed and which one to download if it's not the current one.

Comment: Sweet. I'd actually seen that before, but had completely forgotten about it.

Comment: Marked as the accepted answer, as it's undoubtedly the *quickest* way to find out the latest version you've got installed. (Provided you've got an internet connection, that is.)

Comment: How get .NET Framework versions installed and NET Core too ?

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/smallestdotnet/ not found

Answer (score 4):

From [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kb00318785.aspx):

> How to determine which versions of the .NET Framework are installed
>   To determine which versions of the .NET Framework are installed, locate the %systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework folder. To open this folder, you can paste this address into a Windows Explorer address bar. The following folders contain the released versions of the .NET Framework:
>
> - v3.5
> - v3.0
> - v2.0.50727
> - v1.1.4322
> - v1.0.3705
>
> ...
>
> To determine which versions of the .NET Framework are installed on a computer, follow these steps:
>
> - Open any one of the folders in the previous list.
> - Right-click the Mscorlib.dll file, and then click Properties.
> - Click the Version tab, and then note the file version.
> - Use the previous list to determine which version of the .NET Framework is installed on the computer, and then click OK.
> - Repeat these steps for each version of the .NET Framework on the computer.

Comment: Nicely RTFM'd. Consider me duly humbled. :(

However, it's still not especially quick. If that's the quickest reliable way to get the info, I think I'm gonna have to write myself a little utility...

Anyway, thanks for the swift answer. :)

Comment: It's clearer if you read the article to which hanleyp linked.

Answer (score 3):

[**GotDotNet 2.00**](http://www.cyprich.com/2006/09/05/gotdotnet-200-detect-net-version/) – Detect .NET Version

[image]

Comment: A-ha! For the record, does that tell you which service packs you've got too?

Answer (score 1):

My favorite tool for detecting installed .NET versions is [ASoft .NET Version Detector](http://www.asoft.be/prod_netver.html).
It tells you **all** versions currently installed, including service packs and the "Client Profile" version. Nothing to install, just an executable.

[image]

Comment: It's updated in 2022 for latest NET version (NET 6)